# Show DrawerLayoutAndroid via ToolbarAndroid using Navigator (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native and I'm doing a simple android app.
I added a DrawerLayoutAndroid that I can drag from the left of my screen. However I'd like to open it when I click on my menu icon in my ToolbarAndroid having a Navigator gave me the error

```
"undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.refs['DRAWER']')"
```

Then I solved this mistake but I got another one being

```
"undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.sidebarRef').
```

My code is this:

MyToolbar.js

```js
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
 StyleSheet,
 View,
 Text
} from 'react-native';

var ToolbarAndroid = require('ToolbarAndroid');

class MyToolbar extends Component {
  render() {
    var navigator = this.props.navigator;
    return (
      <ToolbarAndroid
        title={this.props.title}
        navIcon={require('./icons/ic_menu_white_24dp.png')}
        style = {styles.toolbar}
  titleColor={'white'} 
        onIconClicked={this._onIconClicked}/>
    );
  }
  
  _onIconClicked(){
 this.props.sidebarRef.refs['DRAWER'].openDrawer();
  } 
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  toolbar: {
    height: 56,
    backgroundColor: '#08AE9E',
 width: 370,
 alignItems: 'center'
  }  
});

module.exports = MyToolbar;
```

OpenDrawerFromToolbar.js

```js
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
 StyleSheet,
 View,
 Text,
 Navigator,
 TouchableHighlight,
 TouchableOpacity, 
 DrawerLayoutAndroid,
 ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';

var ToolbarAndroid = require('ToolbarAndroid');
var MyToolbar = require('./MyToolbar');
var MenuItem = require('./MenuItem');

class OpenDraweFromToolbar extends Component {
  render() {
   
    var navigationView = (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
        <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'left'}}>I'm in the Drawer!</Text>
  <MenuItem
   title="Calendar"
   selected={this.props.activeTab === 'Calendar'}
   //onPress={this.onTabSelect.bind(this, 'schedule')}
   icon={require('./icons/ic_today_black_24dp.png')}
   //selectedIcon={scheduleIconSelected}
  />
  <MenuItem
   title="Offers"
   selected={this.props.activeTab === 'Offers'}
   //onPress={this.onTabSelect.bind(this, 'schedule')}
   icon={require('./icons/ic_today_black_24dp.png')}
   //selectedIcon={scheduleIconSelected}
  />
  <MenuItem
   title="Boats"
   selected={this.props.activeTab === 'Boats'}
   //onPress={this.onTabSelect.bind(this, 'schedule')}
   icon={require('./icons/ic_directions_boat_black_24dp.png')}
   //selectedIcon={scheduleIconSelected}
  />
  <MenuItem
   title="Profile"
   selected={this.props.activeTab === 'Profile'}
   //onPress={this.onTabSelect.bind(this, 'schedule')}
   icon={require('./icons/ic_account_circle_black_24dp.png')}
   //selectedIcon={scheduleIconSelected}
  />  
      </View>
    );
   
    return (
   <DrawerLayoutAndroid
  drawerWidth={300}
  drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
  renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}
  ref={'DRAWER'}>  
  <MyToolbar style={styles.toolbar}
   title={'Calendar'}
   navigator={this.props.navigator}
   sidebarRef={this}/>       
  <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center'}}>       
    <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'right'}}>Hello</Text>
    <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'right'}}>World!</Text>
  </View>
   </DrawerLayoutAndroid>  
    );
  }
  
  gotoPersonPage() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      id: 'PersonPage',
      name: 'hola',
    });
  }
  
  _setDrawer() {
    this.refs['DRAWER'].openDrawer();
  }  
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  toolbar: {
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: '#08AE9E',
 width: 370,
 alignItems: 'center'
  }
  
});

module.exports = OpenDraweFromToolbar;
```

and calendarpage.js

```js
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
 StyleSheet,
 View,
 Text,
 Navigator,
 TouchableHighlight,
 TouchableOpacity, 
 DrawerLayoutAndroid,
 ScrollView,
 MenuItem,
} from 'react-native';

var ToolbarAndroid = require('ToolbarAndroid');
var MyToolbar = require('./MyToolbar');
var OpenDrawerFromToolbar = require('./OpenDrawerFromToolbar');

class CalendarPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
   <Navigator
    initialRoute = {{ name: 'OpenDrawerFromToolbar', index: 0 }}
    renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
    configureScene={ () => { return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight; }}
  />    
    );
  }
 
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
  //_navigator = navigator;
      return (
          <OpenDrawerFromToolbar
            route={route}
            navigator={navigator}
            //data={route.data}
     />
      );
  }
}

module.exports = CalendarPage;
```

Does someone know what should i try to solve this mistake? i checked this same forum and found similar answers but none of them worked for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass drawerlayout opening method as props to toolbar like this:

```
sidebarRef={()=>this._setDrawer()}
```

And in your toolbar component you should call sidebarRef as props, which automatically call the drawerlayout opening method of previous OpenDraweFromToolbar.js like this:

```
 onIconClicked={this.props.sidebarRef}
```

Finally your toolbar icon will be called. This might help you.